# Types for object literal and function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making a function where it takes type and field as its arguments.

Basically functions first argument is key of object errorTypes, and the second argument is errorArgTypes.

I am getting an error // All type parameters are unused; for below code.

please advise.

```
type errorArgTypes = {
  field: string;
};

const errorTypes = {
  INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: {
    code: 500,
    message: "Internal Server Error ",
  },
  AUTH_NOT_FOUND: {
    code: 401,
    message: "User Not Found ❗️",
  },
  AUTH_ALREADY_EXIST: {
    code: 404,
    message: "User Already Existed ",
  },
  AUTH_NOT_MATCH: {
    code: 402,
    message: "Email or Password Not Match ",
  },
  AUTH_NO_PERMISSION: {
    code: 403,
    message: "No Permission ",
  },
  DATA_NOT_FOUND: {
    code: 401,
    message: "No Data ",
  },
};

type typeOfError = key in  errorTypes;

const foo = {
  "hello": "hola"
};

let data: { [key in keyof typeof foo]:number} & { name: string, index: number }[] = [] as any;



function prop<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
  return obj[key];
}

// All type parameters are unused;

const BaseError = <Key extends keyof typeOfError, errorArgTypes>(type, arg?) => {
  const { code, message } = errorTypes[type];
  return new ApolloError(message, code, arg);
};
```

Comment: Please use `keyof typeof errorTypes` instead of `key in errorTypes`.
What type are you expecting here: `type, arg?`   ?

Comment: [I cannot replicate the error you describe](https://tsplay.dev/Gm3gbm). The TS playground shows an error in `BaseError` because of `noImplicitAny` but doesn't say the parameters are unused. Turning off the rule leaves two other errors - `key in  errorTypes` being invalid syntax and `ApolloError` not being defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```js
const errorTypes = {
  INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: {
    code: 500,
    message: "Internal Server Error ",
  },
  AUTH_NOT_FOUND: {
    code: 401,
    message: "User Not Found ❗️",
  },
  AUTH_ALREADY_EXIST: {
    code: 404,
    message: "User Already Existed ",
  },
  AUTH_NOT_MATCH: {
    code: 402,
    message: "Email or Password Not Match ",
  },
  AUTH_NO_PERMISSION: {
    code: 403,
    message: "No Permission ",
  },
  DATA_NOT_FOUND: {
    code: 401,
    message: "No Data ",
  },
};

type errorArgTypes = {
  field: string;
};

const BaseError = <
  Key extends keyof typeof errorTypes,
  errorArgTypes
>(type: Key, arg?: errorArgTypes) => {
  const { code, message } = errorTypes[type];

  return new ApolloError(message, code, arg);
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgJwSBAVAngBzhGBeGAbwFgAoGGASQDlUBRAJWoEEAZAfQGVGA1R9xgwDyDAFxEyFCqAAmccQFYADEoA0kqQFscEAIYBzeTABElMFERhdAGxidEAN0Qw6SFDEC8G4FY94%20vIwAXz8KZgBVVAAJdmohVHYAMSFQ6gARcRJ-aRA5cQAWJQBGYK0dAyNjUIhnahBYeJAAVzAZGEB1ckB4P98NII0wyPY2BjpmFIBNAQANSk5UdI0snJh83OKKbQg9Q3EKqoQYZmsEOF0ZdBcADwBLaDgWj0ABHa7-Hv8%20qJi4gFlmVABhCLmmRgsiM%20QATKsYOtNuU6JpdJdbO4AAq6DYAdxQLRqsE%20uigwAAFjBAHwbgEVdp4UF4hcLvITsZGMT7TTiUITUQFSYHZUFKADMkOhZW2NRgyMQmmuEEu4E8gGpdymBYopH7MaKxBJJVKcqQgvKFQWlLYmUUpfG6TyAVD3FS8AgBuMhkKBYODwNwIZgIfQYbC4AgZCgAM0ucGsMnE0AQlzA%20gdpHtjtIoEgsAAQmi4K5kHsCAAeDQAaTgZzg5wszVwAGtiyBAzBndha27sz6cMVENnPd6XRAyAA%20AAUDaMRfQqhgui9AH5xB2UF3WxAAJT4PsSfzJ6BEblycdCwyBfDNlCLgDaw4AunGNEcoA0EGAYGA4Oj9pgQNZrCAsygB-u4OOILjpO%20hLnG9pAA)